# How to fix issue height Scrollview Android

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am new to mobile programming, while I was working on my initial portfolio, I had several problems including "How to adjust scrollview height based on content?" here I have set the height to wrap_content but the displayed result is truncated, like the first image.
The results should be displayed if you follow the content, like the second image.

that's all, thanks for wanting to answer, sorry if my english is so bad...

[Pict 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z163x.jpg)

[Pict 2 Item Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKsGX.png)

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchMain"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearPopular"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/cv_slider_mainActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryBackground="@null"
            app:queryHint="@string/search_manga"
            app:showDividers="end">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Terbaru"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_terbaru"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="380dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_row" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Popular"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_popular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_row_card" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView ` instead of `ScrollView` and to remove layout hirarcy use `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: do you set the height of recyclerview item fixed or wrap content